# Negative Active Thread Count in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

We're getting negative thread count in JMeter for active threads.

The test plan contains various Http Web Test Plan related components and samplers using [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampling-for-jmeter). This is creating problems for us in getting correct metrics as JMeter is emitting the same -ve values to the listeners for active threads. Any insights what might be wrong and how to fix this?

Here's the screenshot from the test plan while executing -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all don't run JMeter in GUI mode, it's only for tests development and/or debugging, when it comes to test execution you should [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)
2. I don't think you should have [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampling-for-jmeter) as the first parent sampler, the most obvious use case is simulating [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests, concurrency should be set on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. We are running JMeter in non-GUI distributed mode where we observed negative active threads count in metrics and reproduced this issue on local via JMeter GUI. Can you please throw some light on #2 and if possible on why parallel controller might be resulting into this behavior?